# How to install Litle Magento plugin?

Tags: magento

I see in your example for submitting a token that we're supposed to submit the expiration, card type and CVV again.  I can store the expiration and card type at the time I get the token, but I was told that we're not allowed to store the CVV number.  I thought that the token was supposed to store that information also, was I mistaken?  Do I need to make the customer re-enter their CVV number on each order or is there a way to connect the token to the CVV number?

Answer (score 0):

As long as CVV is collected and sent on the initial registration of the card via PayPage, you can use what Litle has (temporarily) stored by including the  element in the transaction, but instead of setting it to a real value you would set it to 000. Sending 000 as the CVV tells Litle to use, if possible, what is on file. The CVV is stored for 24 hours or until the first Auth, whichever happens first.